# How do I gzip compress a string in Perl

Tags: perl, compression, gzip

I have a string that I would like to compress using GZip before inserting into a database as a BLOB. However, it seems that the built in GZip Perl modules are all designed to compress files, not inline strings.

In PHP I would accomplish this with **$compressed = gzcompress($string)**

What is a Perl equivalent of PHP's gzcompress()?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a `gzip` function in [IO::Compress::Gzip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Compress::Gzip) that should do what you need. Something like this:

```
gzip \$input => \$output
```

would be more or less equivalent to your PHP. Note the use of references to scalars if you want to do everything in memory buffers, if you use plain scalars then `gzip` will think they're filenames.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. The "scalar reference" bit in the documentation was throwing me off.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Gzip.html ?

Answer (score 1):

```
use Compress::Zlib;
#then $out = compress($in) or $out = uncompress($in)
```